# Specifying SQL script with multiple statements for sqlcmd in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sqlcmd

I need to query across multiple (several) databases to see if there is a specific SQL Server Agent Job name on each. I would have thought that SEMICOLON characters would separate SQL statements, but no combination of them seems to work. Am I stuck with specifying `` `r`n `` to separate statements? Is there a better way?

```
@('DBDEV','DBTEST','DBPROD') |
    ForEach-Object {
        & sqlcmd -S $_ -q "SELECT '$_', name FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs SJ WHERE name = 'THE_JOB_NAME'`r`nGO`r`nEXIT"
    }
```

Comment: Do here-strings work for this?

Comment: Why not use Invoke-SQLCmd? And if you use `-Q`, there's no need for exit command either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A combination of what was mentioned by AdminOfThings and vonPryz:

```
$query = @"
SELECT Name
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs SJ
WHERE name = 'THE_JOB_NAME'
"@

$databases = @('DBDEV','DBTEST','DBPROD')
foreach ($database in $databases) {
    Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance $_ -Database 'msdb' -Query $query
}
```

Comment: I must have given the wrong impression. The array is a list of server instance names. The database is always `msdb`, but is it also coded into the query.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. thought those were database names, my bad!